# Postgres constraint must always be 1

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
Table A (
   ValueA string,
   ValueB int,
   ValueC boolean,
   Unique(valueA, valueB)
)
```

Got something to work where across all records containing Value A there is only one true set for ValueC. However I also want the constraint to fail if there is no record where Value C is true.
Ie for all records with Value A are equal there must be a value C set to true and no more than once

Case 1: First insert for 'abc' works in this case
('abc', 1, true)

Case 2: First insert for 'abc' fails
('abc', 1, false)

Case 3: Second insert fails 
('abc', 1, true)
('abc', 2, true) 
Currently I cannot get case 2 to work

Comment: Case #2 rightfully should _not_ be working given your current constraints.  What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

> Got something to work where across all records containing Value A there is only one true set for ValueC.

You can use a partial unique index:

```
create unique index on (valuea)
where valuec;
```

Comment: Is it possible to do so without an index?

Comment: No, but why is that a problem  (your attempt to use a unique constraint also adds an index)